# OpenRecord: TypeError: User.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, openrecord.js

*ORM OpenRecord*

I'm getting an error ( `TypeError: User.create is not a function` ) when I do the following:

```
await User.create(req.body.data)
```

When I log User I get this: `[Function: User]`

**Database config:**

```
//config/database/openRecord.js
/** more code above */
let store = new Store({
    database, 
    user, 
    password, 
    host,
    autoConnect: true,
    autoAttributes: true,
    models: require("../../app/models/models")
});
```

**Models:**

```
//app/models/models.js
module.exports = [
    require("./user")
]
```

**Model:**

```
//app/models/user.js
const Store = require('openrecord/store/mysql');

class User extends Store.BaseModel {
    static definition(){
        this.validatePresenceOf(
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'
        );

        this.validatesConfirmationOf('password');
        this.validateFormatOf('email', 'email');
    }

    fullName(){
        return `${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`
    }
}

module.exports = User;
```

Why is it throwing an error when I've clearly defined my object the correct way?

[openrecord github link](https://github.com/PhilWaldmann/openrecord)

[openrecord website documentation](https://openrecord.js.org/#/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small typos are `validatePresenceOf` (should be validate**s**PresenceOf) and `validateFormatOf` (should be validate**s**FormatOf).

However, this is not the error you experience!
I'm pretty sure that you forget to wait until [the store is ready](https://openrecord.js.org/#/setup?id=wait-for-the-store-to-be-ready).

If you use e.g. [express](http://expressjs.com/) I recommend to start listening after the store has loaded:

```
const express = require('express')
const store = require('./store')

const app = express()

async function start() {
  // add middleware ...

  await store.ready()

  // start express server
  app.listen()
}
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not exported the module. For example, we write:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userobj)
```

This is missing